# How to automatically deploy new image to k8s cluster as it was pushed to docker registry?

Tags: kubernetes, dockerhub, continuous-delivery

I have configured dockerhub to build a new image with tags `latest` and `dev-<version>` as new tag `<version>` is appeared in GitHub. I have no idea how to configure Tekton or any other cloud-native tool to automatically deploy new images as they become available at the registry.

Here's my k8s configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: my-app-ingress
    spec:
      rules:
        - http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: my-app-service
                    port:
                      number: 80
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: my-app-service
    spec:
      ports:
        - port: 80
          targetPort: 8000
      selector:
        app: my-app
      type: LoadBalancer

  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: my-app-local-deployment
      labels:
        app: my-app
        type: web
    spec:
      replicas: 2
      minReadySeconds: 15
      strategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
        rollingUpdate:
          maxUnavailable: 25%
          maxSurge: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: my-app
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: my-app
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: regcred
          containers:
            - name: backend
              image: zuber93/my-app:dev-latest
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              envFrom:
                - secretRef:
                    name: my-app-local-secret
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8000
              readinessProbe:
                httpGet:
                  path: /flvby
                  port: 8000
                initialDelaySeconds: 10
                periodSeconds: 5
            - name: celery
              image: zuber93/my-app:dev-latest
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              workingDir: /code
              command: [ "/code/run/celery.sh" ]
              envFrom:
                - secretRef:
                    name: my-app-local-secret
            - name: redis
              image: redis:latest
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've explored [keel.sh](https://keel.sh/docs/). It can handle appearing of new images and deploy them into the cluster.

Comment: If you wanted a solution like this I would recommend ArgoCD which is more mature and more flexible in its customization, more used and with an awesome ui. Im a big fan of it.

Comment: I tried to configure it but there were lots of UI. I am convinced that UI is just for visualization of configs and should not be used for system configuration. But thanks for your advice. Thanks all the contributors!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is:
Either setup a webhook from dockerhub (https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/) to tekton using triggers.

Or (depends on your security and if your cluster is reachable from www or not)

Poll dockerhub and trigger tekton upon new image detection.
(This can be done in many different ways, simple instant service, scheduled cronjob, etc in k8s)

So, you choose push or pull. ;)

I would ask "why not trigger from your git repo directly?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to trigger from git repo because docker hub which I will use in any case to store my images can trigger git repo by itself and since of that all I need is just configure these images auto-deploy